# Construct a real $x$ such that ZF does not prove whether $x\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, logic, irrational-numbers, constructive-mathematics

I have little knowledge of formal logic or set theory. Nevertheless it occurred to me to wonder whether one can give an explicit construction of a real number, such that it does not follow from the usual ZF axioms of set theory whether or not it is rational.

My question is partly motivated by the supposed "proof" of the existence of irrational $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational. It says: if $x=\sqrt2 ^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational, then $x^{\sqrt2}$ is rational. My first reaction is not the standard intuitionist objection, but that it is very hard to prove that ZF can show whether $x$ is rational. (The now known theorem, that $x$ is irrational, is beside the point.) This leads me to ask the same question about $e+\pi$, and so on.

Comment: We have no real reason to suspect that $\pi + e$ being rational is independent of ZFC; the more likely situation is that we just don't have enough knowledge of transcendental number theory to prove yet that $\pi + e$ is transcendental.

Comment: I'm curious: you call it a "supposed "proof"" - do you actually object to it? (Your actual question isn't an objection to the proof's validity, and it seems from your responses to Asaf's answer that you might not object to classical logic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to define $x$ to be $0$ if the axiom of choice holds, and $\sqrt2$ if the axiom of choice fails.

In set theoretic language this is more complicated, as it involves the exact way that we define the real numbers, and how we interpret the language of fields into set theory. But you can take these as black boxes, and end up with the definition above. You can replace $\sqrt2$ for any other irrational number that you'd like to have.

You can also use the above trick to get some sort of odd scenarios. For example, if you replace "the axiom of choice holds" with "ZF is consistent" (which is itself a number theoretic statement), then you get a real number that is provably rational if and only if ZF is inconsistent to begin with.

---

It is important to point, however, that these examples rely on the law of excluded middle, and they are not constructively valid. If you are interested in a constructive system, then you'd have to specify more accurately what system you're interested in.

(But I imagine that one can use some intuitionistically valid incompleteness argument to reproduce the above $x$. After all, we only want something which is provably a real, but not provably a rational number.)

Comment: For an intuitionistically valid proof, let $T: \omega \to \omega$ be a (computable) function so that $T(n) = 0$ unless there is an $m < n$ so that $m$ is a coded proof of $0=1$ in ZFC, at which point $T$ switches to enumerating binary digits of $\pi$.  Then we can prove intuitionistically that this is a total function, and so it enumerates the digits of some real $x$ between $0$ and $1$.  Still working intuitionistically, we can then mimic the usual proof that ZFC cannot prove whether $x$ is rational (ZFC doesn't prove $x \in Q$ and doesn't prove $x \not \in Q$).

Comment: @Chris: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know if ZF decides the rationality of $e+\pi$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I want to know whether, in your opinion, it will be any easier to show that ZF can decide the rationality or otherwise of $e+\pi$, than to show that it is actually irrational (as everyone suspects).

Comment: @Chris: Well, as far as "the usual arguments" go, one can show that standard set theoretic techniques (forcing, inner models) are not suitable for this application (with the minor caveat that if you can prove it is consistently (ir)rational, then it is provably (ir)rational). This sort of leaves that to be somehow equivalent to number theoretic statements. These are not quite questions that set theorists are interested in, so I don't think that anyone is working towards finding that out anytime soon.

Comment: @Carl: I'm not entirely sure about the tags on this question. Would you be so kind and look at them more closely?

Comment: I also don't know what tags would be ideal, but I did edit them a little.

Comment: @Carl: Thanks a lot!